# layer 2 failover within the rack

Tags: failover, switch

what do you do to avoid downtime caused by top-of-the-rack switch hang / malfunction?
some possible solutions are can be found in [this](http://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog46/abstracts.php?pt=MTQwOCZuYW5vZzQ2&nm=nanog46) presentation.

i'm interested in hearing how do you approach the problem when automatic fail-over is necessary.

**edit** some possible options:

- spanning tree run at each server as suggested by womble
- ethernet bonding in active-backup mode as described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-ethernet-bonding-driver-howto.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll answer myself in this case since idea of running STP at the client presented by womble slightly freaks me out. it seems that:

- [bonding](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding) between the server and two independent switches with periodic connectivity checks [ arp_ip_target parameter ]
- RSTP in the core / between switches

is most reasonable solution.

Comment: pQd, what bonding mode are you using as a result? active-backup, balance-alb or other?

Comment: active-backup; i don't need more bandwidth - just resiliency.

Answer (score 3):

For things that need that level of protection (risk/reward calculation justifies the extra expense, given the low probability of occurance -- unless you're buying really shoddy switches they just don't fail very often) I just dual-path everything -- two switches, one hooked to an on-board NIC the other to an off-board NIC (preferably different models/manufacturers, to protect from driver/NIC failure), then the edge switches hook to a pair of distribution or core switches (as appropriate), which then hook up to a pair of core routers, and so on.  Everything's duplicated.

Bonding is configured to test links via ARP and cutover to the other switch in the pair if, say, a core switch dies (although everything is cross-connected too).  Let spanning tree deal with the redundancy, which in my experience is a lot more robust than the author of those slides suggests.

Comment: thanks; do you use LACP or other protocol? what do you mean by 'dual core' switches - single fully redundant device or stacked up multiple chain of them?

Comment: LACP doesn't work across multiple independent switches.  We use separate devices everywhere; stacked switches have a much higher risk of simultaneous failures in my experience.

Comment: ok - so is every machine spanning-tree aware?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: do you set up bridge over vlans under linux? if so - do you mind posting snippet of your config or pointing some example? thanks.

Comment: Yes, we use VLANs extensively.  Snippets of config are distro specific; everything we do is straight out of the relevant docs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We simply don't use 'top of the rack' switches. We either use blades with in-built switches that are trunked back to redundant distribution or core switches or we patch servers straight through to redundant distribution switches (ideally running VSS).